# How do I write something that communicates with a twisted server?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, twisted

I wrote a basic twisted server and it works with a test client (also in twisted).

Here's the server:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints
import pickle
from time import sleep

def function(x, y):
    sleep(2)
    return x+y

class Pickle(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, pickled):
        data = pickle.loads(pickled)
        response = function(*data)
        self.transport.write(pickle.dumps(response))
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class PickleFactory(protocol.Factory):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Pickle()

endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 1234)
endpoint.listen(PickleFactory())
reactor.run()
```

On the client, I'd like to have something like

```
def send(x,y):
    '''Calculates function(x,y) on a remote server'''
    pass
```

that sends a request to the server and blocks until it gets a response. I'm not trying to do anything event-driven/asynchronous in the client. The fact that reactors can't be restarted means that I can't naively use twisted for this.

What's the best way of going about writing `send`? Can I use twisted? Or should I just use something low-level like socket or telnetlib?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not use `pickle` over network connections; it can execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 0):

Using socket (may not be the most elegant):

```
def send(x, y):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('localhost', 1234))
    s.send(pickle.dumps((x, y))
    result = b''
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0: break
        result += data
    s.close()
    return (pickle.loads(result))
```